# Karate: passing java long as long in request

Tags: karate

Below is my simplified example

```
Feature: Get document

  Background:
        * url 'some_url'
        * def basepath = 'some_path'
        
  Scenario: get document

    Given path basepath
    And header Accept = 'application/json'
    And request { 'string_arg': '#(name)', 'id': #(id) }
    When method post
    Then def document = response
```

It is called like below

```
var req = {'string_arg': 'myname','id': request_id };
var response = karate.call("classpath:getDocument.feature", req)
```

Were `request_id` is retrieved from previous call which is like `1612472688416`

It sends request as

`{ "string_arg": "myname", "id": "1612472688416" }`

End service (not in my control) wants it like below -- without double quotes

`{ "string_arg": "myname", "id": 1612472688416 }`

I tried javascript Number, parseInt and even calling java.lang.Long.parseLong but in all cases it ends up being scientific notation like `1.612472688416E12` in request.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#large-numbers

```
* def big = new java.math.BigDecimal(123123123123)
* string json = { num: '#(big)' }
* match json == '{"num":123123123123}'
```